# How to edit HTML formatted text programatically with javascript without dealing with tags and HTML manually

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to edit some HTML formatted text as if it were plain text but without losing the formatting. For example let's say I have this HTML:

```
<div>
<b>
<span style="color: rgb(68, 68, 68);">Gmail is always available <i>wherever</i> you  are, from any device - desktop, laptop, phone or tablet. Download the app or go to&nbsp;</span><a href="https://www.gmail.com/">gmail.com</a><span style="color: rgb(68, 68, 68); font-family: Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 18.1875px;">&nbsp;on your mobile device to get started.
</span>
</b>
<br>
</div>
```

I would like to be able to do something like:

```
trimmed = getTextToEdit();
tokens = trimmed.split(' ');
replacement = "+";
for (var i=0; i<tokens.length; i++) {
    t = tokens[i].toLowerCase();
    if (t == "Gmail") t = replacement;

}
```

And then have t, still be properly formatted.

Is there any way I can edit the text without manually dealing with all the HTML tags and still keeping the formatting? I am ok with using any library for this.

Thanks!

Comment: CKEditor can do this, but it can't prevent users from mangling the underlying HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need html-parsing for javascript.